# Forward-declared type and "non-class type as already been declared as a class type"

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++

I have problem with following code:

```
  template <typename T>
  void foo(struct bar & b);
  struct bar {};
  int main(){}
```

It compiles successfuly on GCC, but fails on MSVC (2008) with following error:

`C2990: 'bar' : non-class type as already been declared as a class type`

Is the code wrong or it's a bug in MSVC?

It works if I add `struct bar;` before template definition.

Comment: Also fails with VC++ 2010. And God, what a horrible IDE for C++ development VS has become!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

And we have our winner:

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/668430/forward-declared-type-and-non-class-type-as-already-been-declared-as-a-class-type

> Thank you for reporting this issue.
>   This is indeed a case of
>   non-conformant behaviour in VC++.
>   However, a simple workaround is to
>   reorder the declarations so that the
>   declaration "struct bar" is known when
>   the template declaration is
>   encountered. Due to the low severity
>   of this bug and our priorities, we
>   regret that we cannot fix the bug in
>   the next release of the compiler but
>   we will consider it for a future
>   release.
>
> Regards,
>
> Tanveer Gani 
>   Visual C++ Team

Answer (score 3):

In most situations, a C (or C++ compiler) works strictly top-to-bottom on your source code.  So you need a [*forward declaration*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_declaration) before you ever attempt to reference `struct bar`, otherwise the compiler will not know that it exists.

Comment: You can make inline forward declaration. Like `void foo(struct bar & b);`. The **struct** keyword here is forward declaration.

Comment: @Hello: Really?  I'm not saying you're wrong, merely that I've never seen this before.  Could you provide a reference?

Comment: @Oli: Try it without the template, it will compile. :)

Comment: @Oli No reference to the standard but for instance Boost.Exception use it to create (tag) types on the fly for `boost::error_info<struct this_is_a_tag, T>` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/exception/doc/error_info.html

Comment: @Oli: Check this code: http://ideone.com/hlPN0. With no "struct" before bar in function declaration, we get _‘bar’ was not declared in this scope_ error.

Comment: @Xeo, @Luc, @Hello: Ok, interesting!  But a quote from the standard would be nice...  otherwise I can't be sure we're not just seeing non-standard compiler behaviour here.

Comment: @Oli: Well, I'd say it's just like every forward declaration. :) Also, this is perfectly valid in C (or rather, the only way without a typedef), and I'm sure it has been adopted into C++ just as-is.

Comment: I don't have access to C++ standard, but all compilers accept this form of forward-declaration, _unless_ it involves function templates. Of course C++ standard could possibly also answer my original question.

Comment: @Xeo: That's a fair point about C.  I guess I was thrown by the fact that one doesn't normally write `struct blah` in C++ (because `blah` normally suffices)...

Answer (score 1):

Anyway, I've posted a bug in Microsoft Connect: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/668430/forward-declared-type-and-non-class-type-as-already-been-declared-as-a-class-type

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have `struct bar {};` somewhere above this block of code (possibly in a header file).  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zfcw8kk9.aspx

**Edit:** Also from the link above:

> C2990 can also occur due to a breaking
>   change in the Visual C++ compiler for
>   Visual C++ 2005; the compiler now
>   requires that multiple declarations
>   for the same type be identical with
>   respect to template specification.

Since `foo` is templated and `bar` is being "forward-declared" in the `foo` argument list, what happens if you move `struct bar {};` above `foo`?

Comment: @Hello Edited base on your comment.

Comment: Replying to your edit: yes, it would work then. Also, _It works if I add struct bar; before template definition._ like I've written in my question.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like valid code. Whatever MSVC is doing, it appears to be some weird non-conforming behavior, from what I can see.